# Casting a String to Boolean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, types, casting, boolean

In Javascript, is there any difference between
`if(!!isLoaded)` and `if(Boolean(isLoaded))`?

I recently started working on an app where the previous developer did this a lot.

I ran a few tests and they both seem to convert strings "true" and "false" to the Boolean type, which I'm assuming is the main reason for doing this.

If they are indeed the same, what is everyone's opinion on which one is more readable?

Comment: Both will convert the strings `"true"` and `"false"` to the boolean value `true`. But yes, they do precisely the same thing.

Comment: more readable doesn't come into it - neither do what you want

Comment: There's little difference between them, and they're also equivalent to `if(isLoaded)` which I think is most readable.

Comment: Yes @Barmar is right (unsurprisingly) — those conversions are mostly used when you really want a real boolean value to keep track of; if it's just an `if` statement, there's no point because the evaluation of the `if` condition will do exactly the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Both `if (!!isLoaded)` and `if (Boolean(isLoaded))` will be equivalent to `if (isLoaded)`, as JavaScript only looks for truthy values for `if` conditions. If you need the specific strings `"true"` and `"false"`, you'll need to compare to that directly with `if (isLoaded === "true")`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel the `!!` is easier to read. They both convert to boolean though.

However like jaromeda mentioned neither will work for this situation. Both string "true" and "false" result in true since values exist.

Answer (score 0):

#### Empty String is already treated as negative condition in JS, Indeed,...

The following are treated as **negative condition** in JS :

- `0`              `const v = 0 ; (!v) && doSomething()`
- Empty string  `const v = '' ; (!v) && doSomething()` ⬅ ⚠️ Attention please since your question is about casting String to Boolean.
- `false`         `const v = false ; (!v) && doSomething()`
- `null`          `const v = null ; (!v) && doSomething()`
- `undefined`     `const v = undefined ; (!v) && doSomething()`

And those 5 values are equals using `==` and not equal using `===`.

---

Otherwise , `v` is treated as **positive condition**.

```js
let zero = 0 ;
let falseVar = false; 

console.log(` zero == falseVar ? `, zero == falseVar);
console.log(` zero === falseVar ? `, zero === falseVar);

let emptyString= ''
console.log(` zero == emptyString ? `, zero == emptyString);
console.log(` zero === emptyString ? `, zero === emptyString);
```